# Old animated TV series where a character has a bracelet that generates a metal suit and finds a second, different one

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I'm having a hard time finding what I'm looking for because I only remember one scene that happened.

The character who I *think* is the MC, wears a silver (or metallic) band/bracelet/bangle on one wrist, which can be deployed, causing it to deploy a full metal suit over them, layer by layer. At one point, they find a gold one which they put on their other wrist, and deploy both at the same time, causing some weird thing to happen as the two powers try to deploy over each other. That's the only thing I remember about the series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say this is an "old" series, but when did you see it?  Where was it?

Answer (score 4):

Was it perhaps **[Legend of the Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Dragon_(TV_series))**?

The plot synopsis reads -

> The show starts when the previous Golden Dragon has passed on to the afterlife and Ang and Ling Leung, seventeen-year-old fraternal twins, born in the year of the Dragon, are next in line for the Golden Dragon power band and user of its mystical abilities to defend the mortal world from evil. Ang has no belief that he will become the Golden Dragon, as Ling is the best fighter at the Dragon dojo. Ling is positive that she will become the Golden Dragon. However, when Master Chin Ho calls upon the power of the Golden Dragon to choose who will be the next golden Dragon, it chooses Ang. Humiliated and furious, Ling storms out of the temple and is tempted by the ultimate dark and evil power of the shadow Dragon. From then on, Ang is forced to fight his own twin sister.

Perhaps the episode you were referring to was [Double Dragon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjT_J-8wqj9AhVj7TgGHeRRBSkQz40FegQIBRAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXoQQys2NIu0&usg=AOvVaw1hr29gZEotvP6vJnvcgMO8), In that episode -

> In episode twenty-six,"Double Dragon", Ling is overtaken by even greater shadow magic by the revived Emperor of the Darkest Yin, who orders her to win the mystical power-band of the Golden Dragon from Ang. However, Master Chin reveals to Ling that the only way for her to rightfully claim the power-band is to kill him. Horrified, Ling fully breaks free of the darkness that has overwhelmed her so long, as she cannot end her own twin brother. Impressed, Chin says how it was all a test for Ling to follow her true path. He explains that, as Ang's twin sister, she can now become a Golden Dragon herself **. Chin merging both the positive and negative energies of the Golden Dragon power-band and the Shadow Dragon band bestows even greater Dragon firepower onto Ang and Ling as double/twin Golden Dragons; and are now twice as strong when they work together as one.**

Answer (score -1):

How about "Witchblade"?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how Witchblade matches the description provided in the question?